# awk, IFS, and file name truncations

Tags: bash, awk

## Updated question based on new information…

Here is a [gist of my code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ad51dc25290413239f6f), with the general idea that I store items in DropBox at:

~/Dropbox/Public/drops/xx.xx.xx/whatever

Where the date is always 2 chars, 2 chars, and 2 chars, dot separated.  Within that folder can be more folders and more files, which is why when I use `find` I do not set the `depth` and allow it to scan recursively.
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ad51dc25290413239f6f

Below is a shortened version of the gist, it won't run as it stands, I don't believe, though the gist will run assuming you have DropBox installed and there are files at the path location that I set up.

```
General workflow:
SIZE="+250k" # For `find` this is the value in size I am looking for files to be larger than
# Location where I store the output to `find` to process that file further later on.
TEMP="/tmp/drops-output.txt" 

Next I rm the tmp file and touch a new one.

I will then cd into
DEST=/Users/$USER/Dropbox/Public/drops

Perform a quick conditional check to make sure that I am working where I want to be, 
with all my values as variables, I could mess up easily and not be working where I 
thought I would be.
# Conditional check: is the current directory the one I want to be the working directory?
if [ "$(pwd)" = "${DEST}" ]; then
    echo -e "Destination and current working directory are equal, this is good!:\n    $(pwd)\n"
fi

The meat of step one is the `find` command
# Use `find` to locate a subset of files that are larger than a certain size
# save that to a temp file and process it.  I believe this could all be done in 
# one find command with -exec or similar but I can't figure it out
find . -type f -size "${SIZE}" -exec ls -lh {} \; >> "$TEMP"

Inside $TEMP will be a data set that looks like this:
-rw-r--r--@ 1 me  staff    61K Dec 28  2009 /Users/me/Dropbox/Public/drops/12.28.09/wor-10e619e1-120407.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 me  staff   230K Dec 30  2009 /Users/me/Dropbox/Public/drops/12.30.09/hijack-loop-d6250496-153355.pdf
-rw-r--r--@ 1 me  staff    49K Dec 31  2009 /Users/me/Dropbox/Public/drops/12.31.09/mt-5a819185-180538.png

The trouble is, not all files will contains no spaces, though I have done all I can to make sure variables are quoted 
and wrapped in parens or braces or quotes where applicable.

With the results in /tmp I run:
# Number of results located as a result of the find `command` above
RESULTS=$(wc -l "$TEMP" | awk '{print $1}')
echo -e "Located: [$RESULTS] total files greater than or equal to $SIZE\n"

# With a result set found via `find`, now use awk to print out the sorted list of file 
# sizes and paths.
echo -e "SIZE    DATE      FILE PATH"
#awk '{print "["$5"]          ", $9, $10}' < "$TEMP" | sort -n
awk '{for(i=5;i<=NF;i++) {printf $i " "} ; printf "\n"}' "$TEMP" | sort -n

With the changes to awk from how I had it originally, my result now looks like this:
751K Oct 21 19:00 ./10.21.14/netflix-67-190039.png 
760K Sep 14 19:07 ./01.02.15/logos/RCA_old_logo.jpg 
797K Aug 21 03:25 ./08.21.14/girl-88-032514.zip 
916K Sep 11 21:47 ./09.11.14/small-shot-4d-214727.png

I want it to look like this:
SIZE    FILE PATH
========================================
751K    ./10.21.14/netflix-67-190039.png 
760K    ./01.02.15/logos/RCA_old_logo.jpg 
797K    ./08.21.14/girl-88-032514.zip 
916K    ./09.11.14/small-shot-4d-214727.png

# All Done
if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
    echo "find of drop files larger than $SIZE completed without errors.\n"
    exit 1
fi
```

## Original Post to Stack prior to gaining some new information leading to new questions…

Original Post is below, given new information, I tried some new tactics and have left myself with the above script and info.

I have a simple script, Mac OS X, it performs a find on a dir and locates all files of type file and of size greater than +SIZE

These are then appended to a file via >>

From there, I have a file that essentially contains a ls -la listing, so I use awk to get to the file size and the file name with this command:

```
# With a result set found via `find`, now use awk to print out the sorted list of file 
# sizes and paths.
echo -e "SIZE          FILE PATH"
awk '{print "["$5"]          ", $9, $10}' < "$TEMP" | sort -n
```

All works as I want it to, but I get some filename truncation right at the above code.  The entire file is around 30 lines, I have pinned it to this line.  I think if I throw in a different Internal Field Sep that would fix it.  I could use \t as there can't be a \t in Mac OS X filenames.

I thought it was just quoting, but I can't seem to see where if that is the case. Here is a sample of the data returned, usually I get about 50 results. The first one I stuffed in this file has filename truncation:

```
[1.0M]           ./11.26.14/Bruna Legal
[1.4M]           ./12.22.14/card-88-082636.jpg 
[1.6M]           ./12.22.14/thrasher-8c-082637.jpg 
[11M]           ./01.20.15/td-6e-225516.mp3
```

Bruna Legal is "Bruna Legal Name.pdf" on the filesystem.

Comment: Use `stat` command for this and avoid parsing `ls` output.

Comment: Who says there can't be a `\t` in OS X filenames?

Comment: I think the problem is that you only print `$9, $10`. That gets the first two words of the filename. You should use a loop and print all columns from `$9` to `$NF`.

Comment: [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @Barmar it is a condition of the system I have made, the files will never have a \t in the filename as I am the one creating the filename or the system will make the filename and make certain there are no tabs.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid parsing the output of `ls` command and do the whole work with `find` using the `printf` action, like:

```
find /tmp -type f -maxdepth 1 -size +4k 2>/dev/null -printf "%kKB %f\n" |
  sort -nrk1,1
```

In my example it outputs every file that is bigger than 4 kilobytes. The issue is that the `find` command cannot print formatted output with the size in MB. In addition the numeric ordering does not work for me with square brackets surrounding the number, so I omit them. In my test it yields:

```
140KB +~JF7115171557203024470.tmp
140KB +~JF3757415404286641313.tmp
120KB +~JF8126196619419441256.tmp
120KB +~JF7746650828107924225.tmp
120KB +~JF7068968012809375252.tmp
120KB +~JF6524754220513582381.tmp
120KB +~JF5532731202854554147.tmp
120KB +~JF4394954996081723171.tmp
24KB +~JF8516467789156825793.tmp
24KB +~JF3941252532304626610.tmp
24KB +~JF2329724875703278852.tmp
16KB 578829321_2015-01-23_1708257780.pdf
12KB 575998801_2015-01-16_1708257780-1.pdf
8KB adb.log
```

---

**EDIT** because I've noted that `%k` is not accurate enough, so you can use `%s` to print in bytes and transform to KB o MB using `awk`, like:

```
find /tmp -type f -maxdepth 1 -size +4k 2>/dev/null -printf "%sKB %f\n" | 
  sort -nrk1,1 | 
  awk '{ $1 = sprintf( "%.2f", $1 / 1024) } { print }'
```

It yields:

```
136.99KB +~JF7115171557203024470.tmp
136.99KB +~JF3757415404286641313.tmp
117.72KB +~JF8126196619419441256.tmp
117.72KB +~JF7068968012809375252.tmp
117.72KB +~JF6524754220513582381.tmp
117.68KB +~JF7746650828107924225.tmp
117.68KB +~JF5532731202854554147.tmp
117.68KB +~JF4394954996081723171.tmp
21.89KB +~JF8516467789156825793.tmp
21.89KB +~JF3941252532304626610.tmp
21.89KB +~JF2329724875703278852.tmp
14.14KB 578829321_2015-01-23_1708257780.pdf
10.13KB 575998801_2015-01-16_1708257780-1.pdf
4.01KB adb.log
```

Comment: Running your command as one line as follows    

    $find ~/Dropbox/Public/drops/* -type f -maxdepth 1 -size +4k 2>/dev/null -printf "%sKB %f\n" | sort -nrk1,1 | awk '{ $1 = sprintf( "%.2f", $1 / 1024) } { print }'
 
I get nothing for the output

Comment: @Scott: `-maxdepth` does not enter into subfolders. Could be that option filtering out all output?